# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views exception when using thread in OnCreate method Xamarin.Android

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, exception, xamarin.android

I have the following screen:

[image]

When I click on `Ponentes` `ImageButton` , after few seconds `SpeakersActivity` opens. After clicking on `Ponentes` `ImageButton` I don't want to stay on its screen for several seconds, but I want `SpeakersActivity` to open immediately with `loadingSpinner ProgressBar` while the data in `SpeakersActivity` is loading. I put the code which causes the delay in a thread in the `OnCreate` method of `SpeakersActiviy`:

```
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    .....
    .....

    loadingSpinner.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //get all the speakers from the db
        allSpeakers = DatabaseHelper.GetAllFromTable<Speaker>("speakers.db");

        //get only the international spakers
        internationalSpeakers = allSpeakers.Where(x => x.Nationality.Equals("international")).ToList();

        //get only the national speakers
        nationalSpeakers = allSpeakers.Where(x => x.Nationality.Equals("national")).ToList();

        //fill in the RecyclerView with data
        speakersRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.speakersRecyclerView);
        speakersLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        speakersRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(speakersLayoutManager);
        speakersAdapter = new SpeakersAdapter(speakers);
        speakersAdapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;
        speakersRecyclerView.SetAdapter(speakersAdapter);

        loadingSpinner.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
    });
    .....
    .....
}
```

I get `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views exception`. What is the cause of that exception and how can I achieve what I want? If there is a single command solution as mine:

```
await Task.Run(() => {.....});
```

it would be better, so if another person reads my code in the future, he doesn't wonder too much what's going on.

Here is the `SpeakersActivity.axml` :

```
<LinearLayout>
    <Toolbar>
        <TextView/>
    </Toolbar>
    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView/>
        <TextView/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id = "@+id/speakersRecyclerView"/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id = "@+id/loadingSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/animdraw"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I skipped View's attributes because they are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

This is a thread issue, What you need to know is that all the Views that are generated on your UI are created in the MainThread which is also called as UIThread.

Now, this is a general concept that if you have a View only the thread that creates it can modify it i.e. the UIThread now the question arises how do you do that when the code running is on a Background or a secondary thread regardless of who created it? So the platform that you use usually gives that way to you.

For instance Android,

Android has a method in its `Activity` class which is called `RunOnUiThread` now this is the method that you use when there is something that needs to be done on the UI but you are on a background thread. iOS has a method too which is called `InvokeOnMainThread`, XF has `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`!

Now, for your situation, you add a background task that lazy loads your View, which is cool now you need to understand that this is not on the main thread as you created a Task that is supposed to run on another thread through `Task.Run` so now you use the Trick method that we talked about where ever you play with the Views:

Note I might miss something because I do not know the whole code but you can do the rest on your own if you get the basics so here goes nothing:

```
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    .....
    .....
loadingSpinner.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    //get all the speakers from the db
    allSpeakers = DatabaseHelper.GetAllFromTable<Speaker>("speakers.db");

    //get only the international spakers
    internationalSpeakers = allSpeakers.Where(x => x.Nationality.Equals("international")).ToList();

    //get only the national speakers
    nationalSpeakers = allSpeakers.Where(x => x.Nationality.Equals("national")).ToList();
  RunOnUiThread(()=>
  {
    //fill in the RecyclerView with data
    speakersRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.speakersRecyclerView);
    speakersLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    speakersRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(speakersLayoutManager);
    speakersAdapter = new SpeakersAdapter(speakers);
    speakersAdapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;
    speakersRecyclerView.SetAdapter(speakersAdapter);

    loadingSpinner.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
});
});
    .....
    .....
}
```

Goodluck feel free to get back if you have questions!

Answer (score 0):

It's working, the only issue is that the `loadingSpinner ProgressBar` is spinning during half of the loading time. For example, if it takes 4 seconds to load `SpeakersActivity` after `Ponentes ImageButton` has been clicked, the `loadingSpinner` is spinning for 1 or 2 seconds and then it stays still until `SpeakersActivity` data is shown, like that:

[image]

Here is the whole `SpeakersActivity` code:

```
[Activity(Label = "SpeakersActivity", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class SpeakersActivity : BaseActivity
{
    TextView internationalSpeakersTextView;

    TextView nationalSpeakersTextView;

    RecyclerView speakersRecyclerView;

    // Layout manager that lays out each card in the RecyclerView:
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager speakersLayoutManager;

    // Adapter that accesses the data set (speakers):
    SpeakersAdapter speakersAdapter;

    /// <summary>
    /// List that contains all the speakers
    /// </summary>
    List<Speaker> allSpeakers;

    /// <summary>
    /// List that contains the international speakers
    /// </summary>
    List<Speaker> internationalSpeakers;

    /// <summary>
    /// List that contains the national speakers
    /// </summary>
    List<Speaker> nationalSpeakers;

    ProgressBar loadingSpinner;

    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SpeakersActivity);

        Android.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        toolbar.NavigationOnClick += delegate
        {
            this.OnBackPressed();
        };

        loadingSpinner = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.loadingSpinner);
        loadingSpinner.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //get all the speakers from the db
            allSpeakers = DatabaseHelper.GetAllFromTable<Speaker>("speakers.db");

            //get only the international spakers
            internationalSpeakers = allSpeakers.Where(x => x.Nationality.Equals("international")).ToList();

            //get only the national speakers
            nationalSpeakers = allSpeakers.Where(x => x.Nationality.Equals("national")).ToList();

            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                speakersRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.speakersRecyclerView);
                speakersLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                speakersRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(speakersLayoutManager);
                LoadSpeakers(internationalSpeakers);

                loadingSpinner.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            });
        });

        internationalSpeakersTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.internationalSpeakersTextView);
        internationalSpeakersTextView.Click += delegate
        {
            //change TextViews's style when selected/not-selected
            internationalSpeakersTextView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.textView_selected);
            nationalSpeakersTextView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.textView_unselected);

            LoadSpeakers(internationalSpeakers);
        };

        nationalSpeakersTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nationalSpeakersTextView);
        nationalSpeakersTextView.Click += delegate
        {
            //change TextViews's style when selected/not-selected
            nationalSpeakersTextView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.textView_selected);
            internationalSpeakersTextView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.textView_unselected);

            LoadSpeakers(nationalSpeakers);
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load speakers inside activity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="speakers">speakers</param>
    private void LoadSpeakers(List<Speaker> speakers)
    {
        speakersAdapter = new SpeakersAdapter(speakers);
        speakersAdapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;
        speakersRecyclerView.SetAdapter(speakersAdapter);
    }

    private void OnItemClick(object sender, string speakerResumeUrl)
    {
        var speakerDetailsActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(SpeakerDetailsActivity));
        speakerDetailsActivity.PutExtra("speakerResumeUrl", speakerResumeUrl);
        StartActivity(speakerDetailsActivity);
    }

    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        StartActivity(typeof(CongressActivity));
        Finish();
    }
}
```

Here is `ProgressBar` view from `SpeakersActivity.axml`:

```
<ProgressBar
     android:id = "@+id/loadingSpinner"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/animdraw"
     android:visibility="gone"
     android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

And here is `animdraw.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/spinner"
    android:fromDegrees="0.0"
    android:pivotX="50.0%"
    android:pivotY="50.0%"
    android:toDegrees="360.0" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please mark your reply as answer it will help others who have similar issue.